# Forward facebook ads deep links to existing deep link handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook

I work on an app that has already implemented deep link handling using Branch. Deep links are handled in `AppDelegate`'s `openURL` method.

The app is also on Facebook. Now, Facebook Ads Helper shows an ugly red cross and says I need to call `[FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:]` in the Facebook SDK method in order to receive deep links after installs.

I have 2 questions:

1. Do I need to do this? I.e. will Facebook send me deep links in a way that cannot be handled by my existing system?
2. If so, where is the "Facebook SDK method" where this should be called? I saw an example that put this in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. Is this correct?

I realize these are things I can find out for myself by testing 
(and I probably will), but am asking for completeness since I didn't find info on the internet.